# undo method for a paint program (Java)

Tags: java, graphics, paint, undo

I'm trying to create an undo method for a basic paint program. Currently, you can change size and color of the brush, and erase. I'm trying to undo by saving the previous screen as an image (last), and when undo is called, painting that image. I've tried a few things, but nothing has worked. Simply drawing the image "last" creates an identical effect to the clear method. Any ideas?:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.Object.*;

public class Paint extends Applet
{
private int x;
private int y;
private int size = 10;
private int sides = 200;
private int color = 0;
private Rectangle red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, pink, black;
private Rectangle triangle, square, pentagon, hexagon, octagon, circle;
private Rectangle small, medium, large;
private Rectangle eraser, clear, undo;
private Rectangle menuBar;
private Image last;
private Graphics g2;

//defines rectangles
public void init()
{
  setSize(400,600);

  red = new Rectangle(0,0,25,25);
  orange = new Rectangle(0,25,25,25);
  yellow = new Rectangle(0,50,25,25);
  green = new Rectangle(0,75,25,25);
  blue = new Rectangle(0,100,25,25);
  purple = new Rectangle(0,125,25,25);
  pink = new Rectangle(0,150,25,25);
  black = new Rectangle(0,175,25,25);

  triangle = new Rectangle(0,200,25,25);
  square = new Rectangle(0,225,25,25);
  pentagon = new Rectangle(0,250,25,25);
  hexagon = new Rectangle(0,275,25,25);
  octagon = new Rectangle(0,300,25,25);
  circle = new Rectangle(0,325,25,25);

  small = new Rectangle(0,355,25,25);
  medium = new Rectangle(0,370,50,50);
  large = new Rectangle(0,420,100,100);

  eraser = new Rectangle(0,520,50,25);
  clear = new Rectangle(0,545,60,30);
  undo = new Rectangle(0,575,60,30);

  menuBar = new Rectangle(0,0,70,650);
}

//paints the blocks of color in the menu bar
public void paintColors(Graphics g)
{
  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.fillRect(0,0,25,25);
  g.setColor(Color.orange);
  g.fillRect(0,25,25,25);
  g.setColor(Color.yellow);
  g.fillRect(0,50,25,25);
  g.setColor(Color.green);
  g.fillRect(0,75,25,25);
  g.setColor(Color.blue);
  g.fillRect(0,100,25,25);
  g.setColor(new Color(160,32,240));
  g.fillRect(0,125,25,25);
  g.setColor(Color.pink);
  g.fillRect(0,150,25,25);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.fillRect(0,175,25,25);
}

//paints the shapes, eraser, clear, and undo in the menu bar
public void paintShapes(Graphics g)
{
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  Utility.fillTri(g,12,212,25);
  g.fillRect(2,227,20,20);
  Utility.fillPent(g,12,262,25);
  Utility.fillHex(g,12,287,25);
  Utility.fillOct(g,12,312,25);
  Utility.fillPoly(g,12,337,25,300);

  g.fillOval(2,355,10,10);
  g.fillOval(2,370,50,50);
  g.fillOval(2,420,100,100);

  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.drawRect(1,521,52,26);
  g.setColor(Color.pink);
  g.fillRect(2,522,40,25);

  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,20));
  g.drawString("CLEAR",2,580);
  g.drawString("UNDO",2,610);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{ 
  g2 = getGraphics();

  g2.setColor(Color.white);
  g2.fillRect(0,0,60,getHeight());
  paintColors(g2);
  paintShapes(g2);

  draw(g2);
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
  getColor(g);

  Utility.fillPoly(g,x,y,size,sides); //fills a regular polygon with specified center, size, and number of sides
}

public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int xx, int yy)
{
    x = xx;
    y = yy;

  if(red.inside(xx,yy))
     color = 0;
  else if(orange.inside(xx,yy))
     color = 1;
  else if(yellow.inside(xx,yy))
     color = 2;
  else if(green.inside(xx,yy))
     color = 3;
  else if(blue.inside(xx,yy))
     color = 4;
  else if(purple.inside(xx,yy))
     color = 5;
  else if(pink.inside(xx,yy))
     color = 6;
  else if(black.inside(xx,yy))
     color = 7;

  if(triangle.inside(xx,yy))
     sides = 3;
  else if(square.inside(xx,yy))
     sides = 4;
  else if(pentagon.inside(xx,yy))  
     sides = 5;
  else if(hexagon.inside(xx,yy))
     sides = 6;
  else if(octagon.inside(xx,yy))
     sides = 7;
  else if(circle.inside(xx,yy))
     sides = 200;

  if(small.inside(xx,yy))
     size = 10;
  else if(medium.inside(xx,yy))
     size = 50;
  else if(large.inside(xx,yy))
     size = 100;

  if(eraser.inside(xx,yy))
     color = 8;

  if(clear.inside(xx,yy))  
     clear(g2);
  else if(undo.inside(xx,yy))
     undo(g2);

  if(!menuBar.inside(xx,yy))
     last = createImage(getWidth(),getHeight());

    return true;
}

public boolean mouseDrag(Event e, int xx, int yy)
{
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
  if(!menuBar.inside(xx,yy))
     repaint();

    return true;
}

public void update(Graphics g)
{
    paint(g);
}

public void clear(Graphics g)
{
  color = 8;
  getColor(g);
  g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
  color = 0;
  repaint();
}

public void undo(Graphics g)
{

{

public int getColor(Graphics g)
{
  switch(color){
  case 0: g.setColor(Color.red);
  break;
  case 1: g.setColor(Color.orange);
  break;
  case 2: g.setColor(Color.yellow);
  break;
  case 3: g.setColor(Color.green);
  break;
  case 4: g.setColor(Color.blue);
  break;
  case 5: g.setColor(new Color(160,32,240));
  break;
  case 6: g.setColor(Color.pink);
  break;
  case 7: g.setColor(Color.black);
  break;
  case 8: g.setColor(new Color(238,238,238));
  break;
  }

  return color;
}
}
```

Comment: Side note on code quality: your long long if/else states ... just horrible code. Get rid of it, or maintenance will quickly turn into nightmares for you. For the actual question: you might want to study the *Command* pattern. Instead of saving whole images (what sounds like a very resource consuming idea) you might want to make sure that each "change" to a painting ... is actually some kind of command object; that remembers: you did draw a circle, x,y, radius, color. You keep all "applied" commands in a queue; and "undo" means to drop the last entry.

Comment: no it doenst work and you have to include everything

Comment: gpasch, it does work. I'm running it now on my computer. It compiles and runs, but the undo method has a logic error.

Comment: Have you considered using the [UndoManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html)? This would make each "Edit" self-sufficient for deleting itself and reinstantiating itself. In this case, the edit would know its own ID and tell the root panel to delete it.

Comment: can undomanager be used with graphics? I looked over it quickly and I don't think i would be able to use it without changing a significant portion of my other code

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to use some variant of `Command` pattern to handle history.

Swing has a simple history manager named [UndoManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html). Generally it's used with text editors, but it works fine also with custom commands.

If you don't want to use Swing or `UndoManager` is not fit to your requirements, then make a try with an alternative standalone solution or implement your own. [I also implemented my own](https://github.com/davidsusu/command-history-manager) for a large cross platform application.

So, you should wrap all your editing methods to command classes which implement a common interface (e. g. `Command` or `UndoableEdit`) and have methods for "do" and "undo".

It is harder to implement commands for graphics then for text documents where you need to store only minimal information about the edit. Store the changed area's rectangle from the original image on "do" and restore on "undo".

Answer (score 0):

You add to the undo list on every mousedown even if the mousedown doesn't change the image.

So, when you click on the undo option you first save the image and then restore that same image.

You should only save to the undo list just before the image actually gets modified by the user.

Comment: Ok thank you. That does help. However, the undo method currently just clears the screen completely.